# How to display fields of an entity reference field?

Tags: 8, entities

My content type have an "entity reference field" related to another content type.

The only option I have is to display a link to the entity.

[image]

How can I display other fields from this entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose `rendered entity` instead of `label`.

[image]

After that click the options button (cog wheel) and choose the `view mode` of the rendered entity.

[image]

You can go the referenced content type's `manage display` and modify the chosen `view mode` to display the fields that you want

[image]

**NOTE** 
you can enable more display modes from `manage display > Default > custom display settings`

[image]

and can also create your own `view mode` by pressing `manage view modes` on the bottom of the same screen