# Render an image that is located inside a Paragraph that is inside an Entity Reference

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I'm working with Drupal 8.

I have a content type called Lawyer.

This content type has an Entity reference called Firm.

In Firm (which is another content type) I have a Paragraph with an image field in it.

I need to render this image inside node--lawyer.html.twig

I have tried several ways to do it but I can't make it work. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumming a `firm` content type has `field_paragraph` which holds `field_image` of 1 image

for comparison to get *firm name* in twig file you will use

```
{{node.field_firm.entity.title.value}}
```

for *firm paragraph image field value*

```
{{node.field_firm.entity.field_paragraph.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value}}
```

To get the rendered image

```
{% 
  set firm_image = {
    '#theme':      'image_style',
    '#style_name': 'thumbnail',
    '#uri':        node.field_firm.entity.field_paragraph.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value,
    '#attributes': { class: 'yourclass' },
  } 
%}
{{firm_image}}
```

**Alternative** way to [get referenced entity fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256915/how-to-display-fields-of-an-entity-reference-field/256920#256920)

Comment: This is a new solution to me, can I basically create a fake render array in Twig by creating an array with a '#theme' key?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works perfectly! :D You made my day